# Auto importing in excel different files

Tags: excel

I am new in excel. I really don't know how to do this and I will appreciate any help.

I have two files: '1' and '2'.

I want auto import package numbers from file '1' **col B** to file '2' **col b** due to their **PACKAGE** numbers in **col A**.

[image: attached photo]

Comment: Assuming both workbooks are open, =vlookup() would be all that is required.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming both workbooks are open, =vlookup() would be all that is required